# Check if a temp table exists when I only know part of the name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a function for checking if certain tables exist in my database, using part of the table name as a key to match (my table naming conventions include unique table name prefixes). It uses a select statement as below, where `@TablePrefix` is a parameter to the function and contains the first few characters of the table name:

```
DECLARE @R bit;

    SELECT @R = COUNT(X.X)
        FROM ( 
          SELECT TOP(1) 1 X FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] LIKE @TablePrefix + '%' 
        ) AS X;
    
RETURN @R;
```

My question is, how can I extend this function to work for #temp tables too?

I have tried checking the first char of the name for # then using the same logic to select from `tempdb.sys.tables`, but this seems to have a fatal flaw - it returns a positive result when any temp table exists with a matching name, even if not created by the current session - and even if created by SPs in a different database. There does not seem to be any straightforward way to narrow the selection down to only those temp tables that exist in the context of the current session.

I cannot use the other method that seems universally to be suggested for checking temp tables - `IF OBJECT('tempdb..#temp1') IS NOT NULL` - because that requires me to know the full name of the table, not just a prefix.

Comment: Surely you know more of the objects name that *nothing*.... If not, even if you do find objects you have no idea what you're looking for. This feels like a  [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Thanks @Larnu - Well, the problem as stated reflects part of the way the application currently works. I just need to know if any one temp table exists from amongst a group of tables that _could_ exist, which all start with the same prefix as part of the name - e.g. `[name] LIKE '#DNA_%'` . There are certainly other, probably better, ways to solve this problem, but they would require me to recode some parts of the application, which I was hoping to avoid. Anyhow, maybe that's a nettle that I should grasp now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #abc(id bit);
create table #abc_(id bit);
create table #def__(id bit);
create table #xyz___________(id bit);
go

select distinct (left(t.name, n.r)) as tblname
from tempdb.sys.tables as t with(nolock)
cross join  (select top(116) row_number() over(order by(select null)) as r from sys.all_objects with(nolock)) as n
where t.name like '#%'
and object_id('tempdb..'+left(t.name, n.r)) is not null;


drop table #abc;
drop table #abc_;
drop table #def__;
drop table #xyz___________;
```

Comment: Thank you @lptr I have used this approach as the basis for my solution, simply by adding the check on object_id to the select from the tempdb.sys.tables. Also, I only need to know if any one table exists, I have limited the select to TOP(1).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @TablePrefix VARCHAR(50) = '#temp';

    DECLARE @R BIT, @pre VARCHAR(50) = @TablePrefix + '%';

    SELECT @R = CASE LEFT ( @pre, 1 )
        WHEN '#' THEN ( 
            SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] LIKE @pre ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END )
        ELSE ( 
            SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] LIKE @pre ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END )
    END;
    
    SELECT @R AS TableExists;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the problem is that this returns a false positive if there is a temp table with a matching name created by some other process - nothing to do with my application. That's the problem that I had in the first place.